# Use the bin binary on a per-ticker basis

Tags: kdb, qpython, qpython3

For two tables each with datetime and ticker symbol columns, how can we achieve the functionality of the binary function `bin` within each ticker group. That is, instead of returning the latest index from the entire left-table prior to the time of each right-table row, for a given right-table row it should return the latest index from the left-table amongst only the rows of the same ticker symbol as the right-table row.

My first thought would be to add a per-group index in the left-table, apply `bin` on each ticker group for it’s group-index and then use the unique (ticker,group-index) pair to find the index on the full left-table. However, I am not sure how to implement this or if this is the best way to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Could you give some sample inputs and desired output?

This sounds like something you can solve with `aj`

Check https://code.kx.com/q/ref/aj/ for details